# How to deliberately cause a deadlock?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2005

So I'm trying to track down what looks like a deadlock problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811177/how-to-troubleshoot-sql-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-o).  I've enabled deadlock logging using DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1) and DBCC TRACEON(1204 ,-1).  I'd like to test to make sure the logging catches the deadlock, so how can I cause one to occur in MS SQL 2005?  Thanks,

Comment: If the problem in your other post is deadlocks as opposed to blocking you should get a deadlock error rather than a timeout error.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's some T-SQL to deliberately cause a deadlock.

Object creation:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DeadLockTest (col1 INT)
INSERT dbo.DeadLockTest SELECT 1

CREATE TABLE dbo.DeadLockTest2 (col1 INT)
INSERT dbo.DeadLockTest2 SELECT 1
```

Open up a new query window and paste this code and execute it:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE dbo.DeadLockTest SET col1 = 1
```

Open up another new query window and paste and execute this code:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE dbo.DeadLockTest2 SET col1 = 1
UPDATE dbo.DeadLockTest SET col1 = 1
```

Go back to your first query window (with the first `BEGIN TRAN` statement) and execute this code:

```
UPDATE dbo.DeadLockTest2 SET col1 = 1
```

Voila!  That's a deadlock.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

- Insert two records, A and B.
- Open two transactions.
- Update record A in the first transaction and B in the second transaction.
- When you know for sure those updates are done:

  - Update record B in the first transaction and A in the second transaction.