# Scripting a SQL Deadlock to test Retry Logic in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-deadlocks

My company has a SQL job that runs at 12:45 every day. It updates a table that stores various daily prices. At that time, one of our services that uses the table will sometimes error out because of a deadlock. I've been tasked with writing retry logic for the service to try again when it craps out.

What would be the best way to write a script that will lock the SQL table in a transaction so I can run my retry tests against it?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7813646/1280587

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825147/how-to-simulate-deadlock-on-sql-server/22825825#22825825

Comment: My answer got downvoted, so I deleted it.  Please, don't try to reinvent the wheel.  Try Polly (my preference) or Transcient for the c# side.   https://www.nuget.org/packages/polly  and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675232.aspx